# Missing '%I:%M %p' data in Pandas dataframe - Python

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I am dealing with time in a Pandas df that has some datetime with full format: `'%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p',` and some with only: `'%d/%m/%Y'`. As the results, it gives me error when I try to use `pd.to_datetime: 
"time data '24/03/2013'`does not match format `'%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p' (match)"`

Is there a way to add the missing `'%I:%M %p'` into `'24/03/2013'` in the df?

This is the code I use to convert to datetime format:

```
time = pd.to_datetime(samples.DATE_HOURS,format='%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***setup***

```
tidx = pd.date_range('2016-03-31', periods=5)

samples = pd.concat([
        tidx.to_series().dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p'),
        tidx.to_series().dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')],
                    ignore_index=True).to_frame('DATE_HOURS')

print(samples)

            DATE_HOURS
0  31/03/2016 12:00 AM
1  01/04/2016 12:00 AM
2  02/04/2016 12:00 AM
3  03/04/2016 12:00 AM
4  04/04/2016 12:00 AM
5           31/03/2016
6           01/04/2016
7           02/04/2016
8           03/04/2016
9           04/04/2016
```

---

```
# dayfirst=True Thx @NickilMaveli
pd.to_datetime(samples.DATE_HOURS, dayfirst=True)

0   2016-03-31
1   2016-04-01
2   2016-04-02
3   2016-04-03
4   2016-04-04
5   2016-03-31
6   2016-04-01
7   2016-04-02
8   2016-04-03
9   2016-04-04
Name: DATE_HOURS, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

While

```
pd.to_datetime(samples.DATE_HOURS,format='%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p')
```

> ValueError: time data '31/03/2016' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p' (match)

---

Moral of the story, ***don't force the format.  let `to_datetime` figure it out!***

Comment: You forgot to add `dayfirst=True` part.

Comment: Great! It works, thank you. Just curious, why the format is there anyway?

Comment: `format` is there to provide a way to parse less common ways of presenting dates.  However, you wouldn't be able to pass multiple formats.  I'd take a different approach then.  But I'll save that for another question/answer